# How to use my own root certificate for mTLS in Istio?

Tags: istio

I am new with Istio and I want to use my own root certificate for mTLS in Istio.
I am following this doc: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/cert-management/plugin-ca-cert/

I followed the instructions and they work fine.

It creates a secret in `istio-system` namespace with the name `cacerts` to store certificates and Istio uses those certificates as root and intermediate certificates for mTLS.

Now, I want to know 2 things:

1. When I change the secret name from cacerts to cacerts1, Istio no longer uses certificates present in cacert1. What should I do to make Istio use the certificates stored in a secret which is named different than cacert?
2. If my secret (which contains the certificates) is present in different namespace, how do I use that secret?

Answer (score 0):

If you are bringing your own certificate instead of istio's own self signed cert, you have to name the secret file name as cacert. For your second questions, the cacert secret is namespace scoped and has to be in the istio-system namespace only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partially resolve this problem. Let’s say you have a secret named customsecret in namespace istio-system then you can achieve this using this file:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istiocontrolplane
spec:
  components:
    pilot:
      k8s:
        env:
        overlays:
        - apiVersion: apps/v1
          kind: Deployment
          name: istiod
          patches:
          - path: spec.template.spec.volumes.[name:cacerts].secret.secretName
            value: "customsecret"
```

Just make sure you have a secret is present in the namespace istio-system. I could not find a way to use a secret that is not present in istio-system namespace.